# What ndarray.shape returns?

Tags: python, numpy

I am creating an 3 dimensional array.

```
three = np.array([[(1, 2),(4, 5),(7, 8)],
                  [(1, 2),(4, 5),(7, 8)],
                  [(1, 2),(4, 5),(7, 8)],
                  [(1, 2),(4, 5),(7, 8)]], dtype=int)
```

I want to check the output of `three.shape` but I get this: `(4,3,2)` which seems to be (Z, X, Y) and not the convention of Numpy which is (X,Y,Z).

I don't understand why I get this weird output. I appreciate an explanation about it.

Comment: `z = len((1, 2))`, `z == 2`, `y = len([(1, 2),(4, 5),(7, 8)])`, `y == 3`, `x = len(three)`, `x == 4`?

Comment: Why are you expecting a shape of `(3, 2, 4)`? Perhaps we might be able to word it according to your line of thoughts.

Comment: Your 'convention' names don't make sense.  They aren't used in `numpy` documentation.  With 2d arrays we do talk about 'row/column' but that's informal.  You have a 3d array, which is displayed in a 'block/row/column' format.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy reads in your list of lists of tuples from the outside in.  The outer most list contains 4 elements.  Those will each be a "row", or your `X` dimension.

```
[ row
  row
  row
  row ]
```

Each "row" contains 3 tuples, those are the "columns", or your `Y` dimension.

```
[ row( col, col, col )
  row( col, col, col )
  row( col, col, col )
  row( col, col, col ) ]
```

And so forth for the 2 elements in the tuple.

You should expect it be `(4,3,2)`, as that is what you have given to numpy.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding: your top level has 4 elements of [(1,2),(4,5),(7,8)], next level has three elements: (1,2),(4,5), and (7,8), the next level has 2 elements: 1,2, or 4,5, or 7,8.  So the shape is (4,3,2)

Answer (score 0):

Every list in your list is a row and the tuples in them the columns. 4,3,2 means It is a  4 rows,3 columns and it is 2 dimensional  array